# ¿Como puedo configurar un Spinner y su clase interna SpinnerDateModel en JAVA?

Tags: java, spinner, configuración

Quiero crear un formulario, donde pida tus fecha de nacimiento. Como ya saben se puede hacer eso usando un Spinner y su clase interna SpinnerDateModel, pero eso te lo hace en el mismo "JTtextField". Y yo quiero dividir las fechas. Un spinner para día, otro para el mes, y el ultimo para año. Y cuando modifique por ejemplo el mes; cambie el limite de días en el Spinner de días. Por supuesto todo esto en Java.

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? ¿Qué haz escrito hasta el momento? Publicalo.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.